# MySQL database for offline work

Tags: mysql, database

I have a website I'm going through and I've got all it's files. What I didn't get is it's database.

Is there a way I can mimic the database without the real one?

Comment: You can create dummy Data Structures to mimic Database, but will it be worth that much effort. MySQL can run on a local PC why not just do that and import some sample data from all tables.

Comment: The programmer which is currently maintaining the website went on a vacation and will be back in Sunday so until then I don't have access to it

Comment: I recommend to wait until Sunday , but since you have access to all the files means you have access to server , you should be able to export data from DB Server as well.

Comment: He exported the files and gave me. I don't have a live version of it or access to the server.
Is there still a way?

Comment: I would still recommend for waiting until Sunday. As i dont think it is worth to create dummy DS , which will be error-prone as well as require a lot of effort.